# Can you constrain SQL rows based on two fields?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am trying to make a table that has fields: Login and Alert_Code. Each Login should only be able to have an individual Alert_Code once. There can be multiple rows with the same Login.

For example, if Login "AK" has a row with Alert_Code "1", and another row with the same Login "AK" and Alert_Code "2", how can I ensure these Alert_Codes are not used again for that Login?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX AK_Some_Name   
   ON Table_Name (Login, Alert_Code);`

Comment: You could also make a composite primary key when you create the table. Here is a little more information on that https://www.1keydata.com/blog/composite-key-in-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

This is normally handled through a unique constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_login_alert_code
    unique (login, altert_code);
```

This is typically implemented using a unique index.  So, creating a unique index also has the same effect.